# Spring Boot Security - Issues with Logout Redirect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, keycloak

### The Purpose of the Application

So I was working on a very basic app with Spring Boot in Kotlin language and I wanted to integrate an authentication system based on the **Keycloak** authentication management service.

My application consists for now of a many page that asks you to **login** by sending you to a Keycloak login form when you want to access to your profile for your first time. Then after the successful authentication Keycloak automatically manages all the requests to protected content.

Lastly when you're on your profile you have the option to **logout** and once you do you get redirected to a logout page that announces your successful logout and to go back to the homepage.

### My Application Configuration

For starters here's how I setup my application.

This is my Controller :

```kotlin
@Controller
class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/profile")
    fun getProfile() = "profile"

    @GetMapping("/logout")
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun logout(request: HttpServletRequest): String? {
        request.logout()

        return "logout"
    }
}
```

This is my Security Config :

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(keycloakLogoutHandler: KeycloakLogoutHandler?) {
    private final val keycloakLogoutHandler: KeycloakLogoutHandler = keycloakLogoutHandler!!

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/profile").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        .oauth2Login()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()

        return http.build()
    }
}
```

This is my custom Keycloak configured LogoutHandler :

```kotlin
@Component
class KeycloakLogoutHandler : LogoutHandler {
    var logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KeycloakLogoutHandler::class.java)

    private final val restTemplate: RestTemplate = RestTemplate()

    override fun logout(
        request: HttpServletRequest?,
        response: HttpServletResponse?,
        auth: Authentication?
    ) {
        val user = auth?.principal as OidcUser
        val endSessionEndpoint = user.issuer.toString() + "/protocol/openid-connect/logout"
        val builder = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromUriString(endSessionEndpoint)
            .queryParam("id_token_hint", user.idToken?.tokenValue)
        val logoutResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(
            builder.toUriString(), String::class.java
        )
        if (logoutResponse.statusCode.is2xxSuccessful) {
            logger.info("Successfully logged out from Keycloak")
        } else {
            logger.error("Could not propagate logout to Keycloak")
        }
    }
}
```

This is my application.yml :

```yaml
server:
  port: 8081

keycloak:
  realm: http://localhost:8082/realms/StroffosRealm

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: ${keycloak.realm}
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: authenticator-app
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope: openid
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: ${keycloak.realm}
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
```

### The Problem

The application works perfectly for the most part until you try to logout in this profile page :

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Your Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, User!</h1>
    <p>This is your profile</p>
    <a href="/logout"><button>Logout</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

The actual logout request gets sent out correctly from the `KeycloakLogoutHandler` that correctly logs me out of the current session and does not let me access to profile page until I log in back once again.

But the logout confirmation page that I want to display is shown an **Internal Server Error 500** because the `auth` parameter in the `logout()` function of the `KeycloakLogoutHandler` gives me the error :

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUser`

But even when I try to prevent it by simply invalidating the possibility of `auth` being null by putting a

```kotlin
if (auth == null) return
```

control as the first instruction of the `logout()` function, but whenever I or the Logout button tries to redirect to the logout HTML page the result is a [Too many redirects Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6hEW.png)

### What I believe is the Main Issue

Whenever I click the `Logout` button sends me to the `localhost:8081/logout` URL and the mapping in the `@Controller` executes for its first time the `request.logout()` instruction, invalidates my current session and empties the authentication information.
Once it does that it should return the **logout** HTML page but it does not, because once the logout is successful, like it's written in the **SecurityConfig**, the redirect URL would also be `localost:8081/logout` and therefore it would execute for a second time the `request.logout()` instruction, but this time finding an empty `auth` parameter.

### What I've Tried

Removing the `.logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")` from the **SecurityConfig** was my first thought but then once the logout is executed it just redirects me to the [default Spring Security Logout page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z675y.png)

And I obviously do not want it to happen.

## Update

I've cleaned up my `@Controller` and my SecurityConfig:

```kotlin
@Controller
class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/profile")
    fun getProfile() = "profile"

    @GetMapping("/logout")
    fun logoutPage() = "logout"

}
```

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(keycloakLogoutHandler: KeycloakLogoutHandler?) {
    private final val keycloakLogoutHandler: KeycloakLogoutHandler = keycloakLogoutHandler!!

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/profile").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher("/logoutRequest"))
                .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
                .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>::jwt)
        http.csrf().disable()

        return http.build()
    }
}
```

Now whenever a request is sent at the `/logoutRequest` URL it will be threated as a logout request and will correctly redirect me to the logout page.

No more `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` occurring, but now the thing that its showing instead of my custom logout confirmation page is the [default one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxMKh.png) provided by Spring Security, which **I do not want**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but try to add **.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))** in chain after **.logout()**

**EDITED:**

Quote from docs:

> When using the HttpServletRequest.logout() option the adapter executes
> a back-channel POST call against the Keycloak server passing the
> refresh token. If the method is executed from an unprotected page (a
> page that does not check for a valid token) the refresh token can be
> unavailable and, in that case, the adapter skips the call. For this
> reason, using a protected page to execute HttpServletRequest.logout()
> is recommended so that current tokens are always taken into account
> and an interaction with the Keycloak server is performed if needed.

Seems like You have to change controller's mapping to POST and make a button in your HTML-page looking kinda

```
<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
<input type="submit" th:value="LogOut" class="btn btn-warning"/>
```

* in this example Bootstrap CSS and Thymeleaf are used

Comment: Tried and it still gives the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error

Comment: Ok, and if put .permitAll() after .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout") instead ?

Comment: Nope, still the same error

Comment: Check for edition please

Comment: I tried but the error still persists.
In my original code POST request itself is not handled by the controller, but by the LogoutHandler that through a rest template makes the logout POST request to the http://localhost:8082/realms/{my-realm}/protocol/openid-connect/logout URL, the problem is that after the logout is successful the security config tries to **redirect once again to the /logout URL**

Comment: Also without the `.logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")` instruction in the SecurityConfig it would automatically redirect me to the default Spring Security `/login?logout` URL

Comment: As for your update: I think You should rename custom html for /logout action and put something like .logoutSuccessUrl("/{yourCustomPageName}") ,for example .logoutSuccessUrl("/home") like I did in my pet-project.

Comment: Yes I did just that, at the end I managed to solve it, it's just that I really wanted to use **/logout** as the logoutSuccessUrl

Answer (score 0):

You can try separating the endpoint that handles the logic of logging out and the endpoint that displays the successful logout.

For example you could have a `/logout-success` endpoint that returns the wanted html that tells the user the logout was a success and after some time redirects the user to the homepage.

You'd configure `.logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success")` to have the user be redirected after successfully logging out.

Comment: I updated my question as I went for a similar approach to the one you proposed me but another problem arose, which I also explained in the update

Comment: I misinterpreted your answer, your solution actually worked, although I wanted to make **/logout** the actual logout confirmation URL I'll just have do deal with **/logout-success** being the defaut one